# How to make NEW Networking Calls in MVVM?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

**I'm trying to implement pull to refresh with MVVM (and a recyclerview) yet I don't understand how I'm supposed to fetch new data. Inital load up of the app is fine as I'm just observing the livedata from the view model when it's created, but how do I query for more data?**

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.simplenews;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.simplenews.adapters.NewsArticleAdapter;
import com.example.simplenews.adapters.RecyclerItemClickListener;
import com.example.simplenews.models.Article;
import com.example.simplenews.models.NewsResponse;
import com.example.simplenews.repositories.NewsAPI;
import com.example.simplenews.repositories.NewsRepository;
import com.example.simplenews.viewmodels.NewsViewModel;
import com.victor.loading.rotate.RotateLoading;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;

import timber.log.Timber;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView newsRecyclerView;
    private NewsArticleAdapter newsAdapter;
    private NewsAPI NewsAPI;
    private ArrayList<Article> newsArticles = new ArrayList<>();
    private RotateLoading rotateLoadingIndicator;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    private NewsViewModel newsViewModel;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//        Planting timber debug tree here because this joint refuses to work when planted in the application class
        Timber.plant(new Timber.DebugTree());


        swipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
        newsRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.newsRecyclerView);
        rotateLoadingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.rotate_loading_indicator);

//        Getting and setting up the viewmodel
        newsViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(NewsViewModel.class);
        newsViewModel.initNewsViewModel();

//        Setting up the observer
        newsViewModel.getNewsRepositoryQuery().observe(this, newsResponse -> {
            ArrayList<Article> freshNewsArticles = (ArrayList<Article>) newsResponse.getArticles();
            newsArticles.addAll(freshNewsArticles);
            newsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        });


        initReyclerView();


//        This is not the way to do recyclerview click listeners but this will suffice for now
        newsRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
                new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, newsRecyclerView, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        Article article = newsArticles.get(position);
                        Uri uri = Uri.parse(article.getUrl());
                        Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                        startActivity(webIntent);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {
                    }
                })
        );

        // Configure the refreshing colors
        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                newsViewModel.getNewHeadlines().observe(MainActivity.this, new Observer<NewsResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChanged(NewsResponse newsResponse) {
                        if (newsResponse.getArticles() != null) {
                            refreshNewsRecyclerView(newsResponse.getArticles());
                            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        }


                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        Timber.d("the articles in the refresh callback were null");
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }


    /*
     * Helper method that refreshes topHeadlinesRecyclerView with new articles
     * @param: list of new article objects from a network request
     * */
    private void refreshNewsRecyclerView(List<Article> freshArticles) {
        newsRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        showLoadingIndicator();
        newsAdapter.clearNewsArticles();
        newsAdapter.addAll(freshArticles);
        newsRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        hideLoadingIndicator();
        newsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    /*
     * Helper method to show the loading indicator
     * */
    private void showLoadingIndicator() {
        rotateLoadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        rotateLoadingIndicator.start();
    }

    /*
     * Helper method to hide loading indicator
     * */
    private void hideLoadingIndicator() {
        rotateLoadingIndicator.stop();
        rotateLoadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    /*
     * Helper method to setup the recyclerView
     * */
    private void initReyclerView() {
        if (newsAdapter == null) {
            showLoadingIndicator();
            newsAdapter = new NewsArticleAdapter(newsArticles, this);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            newsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            newsRecyclerView.setAdapter(newsAdapter);
            hideLoadingIndicator();
        } else {
            newsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }

}
```

**NewsViewModel**

```
public class NewsViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<NewsResponse> mutableLiveData;

    
    private NewsRepository newsRepository;

    //    When a viewmodel object is created fetch the data needed for the activitiy
    public void initNewsViewModel() {
        if (mutableLiveData != null) {
            return;
        }
        newsRepository = NewsRepository.getInstance();
        mutableLiveData = newsRepository.getTopHeadlines();

    }


    public MutableLiveData<NewsResponse> getNewsRepositoryQuery() {
        return mutableLiveData;
    }

    public MutableLiveData<NewsResponse> getNewHeadlines() {
        MutableLiveData<NewsResponse> response = newsRepository.getTopHeadlines();
        return response;
    }


}
```

**News Repository**

```
public class NewsRepository {
    private static NewsRepository newsRepository;
    private NewsAPI newsAPI;




    private List<Article> freshArticles;


    public static NewsRepository getInstance() {
        if (newsRepository == null) {
            newsRepository = new NewsRepository();
        }
        return newsRepository;
    }

    /*
     * Private constructor because nobody should be creating this object direcly
     * */
    private NewsRepository() {
        newsAPI = RetrofitClient.getRetrofitInstance().create(NewsAPI.class);
    }

    public MutableLiveData<NewsResponse> getTopHeadlines() {
        MutableLiveData<NewsResponse> topHeadlines = new MutableLiveData<>();
        newsAPI.getRootJSONObject().enqueue(new Callback<NewsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<NewsResponse> call, Response<NewsResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    topHeadlines.setValue(response.body());
                    Timber.d("Network call was succesful here is the response code " + response.code());
                } else {
                    Timber.d("Network call was unsuccesful " + response.code());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<NewsResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Timber.d("Network call completely failed lol");
                topHeadlines.setValue(null);
            }
        });
        return topHeadlines;

    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply make a function which reset value of MutableLiveData
For example on swipe call viewmodel.resetNewsHeadlines() and in resetNewsHeadlines() method simple set value to  null and recall mutableLiveData = newsRepository.getTopHeadlines(); again

Comment: Thank you! this set me in the right direction I was overthinking it